# ARC2 (PHP semantic web library) wrongly double-converts UTF-8 file to UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, rdf, utf

Using [ARC2](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki), textual data gets corrupted.

My RDF input file is in UTF-8. It gets loaded in ARC2, which uses a MySQL backend, through a `LOAD <path/to/file.rdf>` query. The MySQL database is in UTF-8 too, as a check with PHPMyAdmin makes sure.

However, the textual data gets corrupted. After several conversion checks, the problem seems to be that the original UTF-8 file is believed to be in ISO-8859-1, and converted to UTF-8 once again.

*Example: "surmonté" → "surmonteÌ".*

This "surmonteÌ" is actulally available in UTF-8 in the database.

Is this related to the way ARC2 opens files (digging through the code, not exhaustively but quite deep, did not show anything suspicious), or could this be a more general case with PHP and MySQL?

How can I make sure the imported data is not wrongly re-encoded but taken as the original?

Comment: Is ARC2 specifying an encoding for the file or the database connection at any point? If not, it'll probably default to latin1, which is where your problem comes from.

Comment: @deceze Yes, this is of course the first thing I checked, and it explicitly [creates the database and collation in UTF-8](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/blob/master/store/ARC2_Store.php#L59).It then does not explicitly state it when connecting to the database, but I don't know if that would have any meaning… ?

Comment: The database and collation is meaningless without the connection encoding. See http://kunststube.net/frontback

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the link, that was an interesting read. Does not solve the problem though, since ARC2 does specify, as linked above, the encoding whenever connecting to the database. I am currently narrowing the bug down, and will try and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC2 uses two functions: `$store->setUp()`, which `CREATE`s `TABLE`s and `DATABASE` if needs be; and `query(LOAD…`, a detailed in the question.

It turns out, the `setUp()` part must *not* be called in the same script as the `load` part. At least, not during the same execution. The solution I took was to make two separate scripts, one to init the database, another to load the data, but simply commenting out the init part once it is done also works. In any case, the trick is to make sure the loading won't take place right after the initialization.

This happens because the `SET NAMES utf8` encoding specification upon DB connection is set only [after collation detection](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/blob/master/store/ARC2_Store.php#L73), for which MySQL does not seem to detect properly if the database has just been created. I made a [pull request](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/pull/23) of a fix.

---

As a side note, it is not efficient to use the `LOAD <path/to/file.rdf` construct of the question: this will be computed as a relative *web* address, calling the server to download from itself through the network. It is much more efficient to use a construct such as:

```
 $store->query('LOAD <file://' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/path/to/file.rdf>')
```